# I'm seeing some pages not load where jquery.min.js is not being cached

Tags: bug

I don't know if this is a bug or some loading/cloudflare configuration issue, but I've been having sporadic slowness on the site the past 4 hours (Tue Nov 17 16:25:40 UTC 2015) on Safari Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9).

Specifically, when looking at questions (not the main site pages), page rendering is blocked by query.min.js not being cached and taking more than 15 seconds to load (most of the time when it takes that long, it will never end up loading)

The rest of the network times look fine, and I do use ghostly extension - but disabling that doesn't seem to affect this issue.

[image]

Is this a bug or a user level / configuration issue?

Comment: Also, the site now loads images from graph.facebook.com - ewww. I'm guessing adzerk is injecting it, but I'll leave that privacy mess for another question.

Comment: I may have to blame comcast on this one... https://mobile.twitter.com/theFNDTN/status/666653847792824320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this so I'll blame the network provider up stream of me rather than the site or the infrastructure that's common to the SE network.